# JointJS - How to change the colour of a link on hover

Tags: jointjs

Does anyone know how to change the colour of a link and its remove button when the mouse cursor is hovered over it?

The JointJS shapes appear to be SVGs so correct me if I am wrong but I don't think I can use CSS to do this...

Answer (score 3):

try this to change you line color to red on hover:

```
this.paper.on({
 'link:mouseenter': (linkView) => {
   linkView.model.attr('line/stroke', 'red');
 }
});
```

Answer (score -3):

Try this May you look something like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
/* unvisited link */
a:link {
  color: red;
}

/* visited link */
a:visited {
  color: green;
}

/* mouse over link */
a:hover {
  color: blue;
}

/* selected link */
a:active {
  color: blue;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p><b><a href="default.asp" target="_blank">This is a link</a></b></p>
<p><b>Note:</b> a:hover MUST come after a:link and a:visited in the CSS definition in order to be effective.</p>
<p><b>Note:</b> a:active MUST come after a:hover in the CSS definition in order to be effective.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

[Check this:](http://jsfiddle.net/x0v24st6/)

Comment: This has nothing to do with jointjs. The question is about jointjs link